# Sorting the divs in jquery

Tags: jquery-ui

I have divided  a page into two divs namely "leftPanel and RightPanel". I am trying to sort two vertical divs on a page using Jquery sortable method.I am confused with what api to use. Do i need to import only Jquery-1.7.2.min.js or do i need to import all the sortable.js, ui-widget.js,mouseover.js and etc.... .Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to this page, and download what you want to use(I would recommend click all)

http://jqueryui.com/download

When it is downloaded, you will see a zip file, unzip it, then you will see all necessary files including Jquery-1.7.2.min.js, jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js, jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.css, and images.

Answer (score 0):

**[jQuery UI's download page](http://jqueryui.com/download)** gives you everything you need. When you select the widgets you want to use, the page packages the appropriate code, including jQuery, into a tidy zip file.